# How do you pronounce “lithe”?

Tags: pronunciation

The word *lithe* seems to be pronounced just like the adjective *live* (as in *alive*), as far as I can tell from listening to [this sound sample](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lithe).

Had I not heard it, I would have expected it to be pronounced like *light*.

Am I hearing it correctly, and could you shed any information on this “special” pronunciation?

Comment: The final consonant in *lithe* is a [voiced dental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_fricative) [ð], not a [voiced labiodental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative) [v].

Comment: i.e. with your tongue, and not the bottom lip, between your teeth.

Comment: @phenry So, does that mean it only sounds like Live, but actually is not?

Comment: *Live* ends in a /v/ sound, as in "have". 

*Lithe* ends in a /ð/ sound, like "breathe".

Comment: All of the comments lead me to think that I am not hearing it correctly - rather, I am hearing it by approximating it to the nearest word I can think of, Live.

Comment: @Sabuncu - They are two different sounds. Non-native speakers often have trouble pronouncing and recognizing the voiced and unvoiced "th" sounds, but most native speakers would probably have little trouble distinguishing between "live" and "lithe" in context.

Comment: Don't mean to digress but up to know I'd always thought that it was pronounced like "lithium" without the "ium". Thank god I've never used it in public! Also, is it just me or does the correct pronunciation sound kinda icky?

Comment: And note that it sounds like the **adjective** _live_ /layv/, and **not** the verb _live_ /lɪv/.

Comment: @seismatica Same here!  I was just reading the Wikipedia entry for Billy the Kid, where he's described as being "lithe as a cat", upon which I decided to look up its pronunciation.

Comment: With few exceptions, words ending in THE (as opposed to TH) are pronounced with the voiced /ð/. This is often a result of verbal voicing: _bath ~ bathe, mouth ~ mouth(e), loath ~ loathe, sheath ~ sheathe, wreath ~ wreathe, breath ~ breathe, teeth ~ teethe, lath ~ lathe, cloth ~ clothe, sooth ~ soothe._ The second one in these pairs is a verb and is pronounced /ð/. Similar things happen with /s ~ z/ but they're not spelled differently: _use_ (n) /yus/ ~ _use_ (v) /yuz/; _house_ (n) /haws/ ~ _house_ (v) /hawz/.

Comment: @JohnLawler I know you know this, but just for the rest of the world, voicing also gets turned on with plurals (well, if they’re old enough) whose singulars end in unvoiced fricatives for the same reason. So /θ/ > /ð/ *mouth > mouths*, /s/ > /z/ *house > houses*, /f/ > /v/ *wolf > wolves*. Doesn’t happen with /ʃ/ > /ʒ/ though as far as I’m aware.  Makes me wonder whether it happened in inflections of OE *Ænglisc* that had a following *e*, like ME *Þe englische barones*; somehow I doubt it, since bare /ʒ/ (rather than affricated /dʒ/) feels like some imported alien French sound in English.

Comment: @tchrist: I was trying to avoid plural morphology. But voicing is not fully phonemic for English fricatives; there's only been a consistent distinction for about 400 years, and each fricative phoneme pair has its own history and oddities. /h/ only has prevocalic allophones, TH has the most minuscule functional load in English, /ʃ/ and /ʒ/ result from all sorts of minor palatalizations, and /s/ and /z/ are almost never spelled out.

Comment: @JohnLawler The instructions you have at your page "How to unwind English syntax" is very useful.  The entire page is actually very useful and full of information that is accessible in a non-intimidating form.

Comment: @Sabuncu: That's the general idea. Glad you like it. [Here's the link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) again.

Comment: There are a number of pairs of phonemes that can be difficult to distinguish when they're heard without seeing the speaker's mouth. When I speak my name _Barry_ on the phone, it's often mistaken for _Gary_, and demonstrations of this effect often used _b_ and _p_. I wouldn't be surprised if non-native speakers have trouble distinguishing _lithe_ from _live_ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone was expecting to hear a word pronounced in the same way as *light* - in other words as /laɪt/, and they then heard this word, they may very well mishear it.

The word is actually /laɪð/. The sound you hear at the end there is a voiced fricative, just like the sound /v/, but it is a *dental* fricative. We make it with our tongues touching the back of our teeth. It is the same sound we hear at the beginning of the word *then*. This sound is most frequently heard at the beginning of 'function words', the types of word you would study in grammar lessons:

- *this*, *that*, *these*, *those*, *them*, *their* ...

Sometimes, however, we hear it in lexical words (the kinds of words we often look up in a dictionary). At the ends of lexical words a particularly common spelling for this sound is -*the*.

As at least one commenter has said, there is often an alternation between a noun of the same root ending in -*th*, pronounced with the *unvoiced* dental fricative, /θ/ ( - the sound at the beginning of the word *think*), and a verb ending in -*the*, pronounced with its voiced counterpart /ð/. Compare the nouns:

- wreath /ri:θ/, sheath /ʃi:θ/

and the verbs:

- wreathe /ri:ð/, sheathe /ʃi:ð/

However, as will be seen from the Original Poster's question, this ending occurs with other parts of speech too. The target word *lithe*, with which we are currently concerned, is an adjective. We can also find nouns such as *swathe*/sweɪð/.

Comment: Rhymes with *blithe, scythe, tithe*, and *writhe* — amongst others.

Comment: Don't forget that non-native speakers are not the only ones to get intradentals and labiodentals mixed up: to many a speaker of Estuary or Cockney English, _lithe_ and _live_ are homonyms, just like _thought_ and _fought_ or _wreath_ and _reef_ are. They are tricksters, these fricatives.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You mean homophonies or phonohomies or something like that. :)

Comment: @tchrist Errr, yes. Exactly. I mean homophones. Homonyms they are not.

Comment: +1 Great, thank you, happy to mark this as the answer.  (I was wondering what I would have to do w/ a question that had several comments which answered my question, but no formal answer.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, lithe is usually pronounced as laɪð, and less commonly as laɪθ (in American English).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that 'lithe' rhymes with 'writhe'.

Comment: This does presume that they know how to pronounce 'writhe' correctly though.